# How to test rspecs configure_devise_params in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

Simplecov is telling me I need test this method (class requires a 100% passing tests in simplecov)

How can I go about testing these in rspec?

```
    before_filter :configure_devise_params, if: :devise_controller?
    def configure_devise_params
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
        u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
      end

     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
       u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
     end
   end
```

I have created an application_controller_spec.rb file.